# Keycloak - login in Pop Up window

Tags: keycloak, okta, keycloak-connect, keycloak-nodejs-connect, okta-signin-widget

I am using keycloak in an iframe. My keycloak client is Okta.

With my current configuration, keycloak simply redirects to okta login page. This means they are beeing opened within the iframe aswell. I'd really like to change that, since it contradicts some major security policies I have.

Can anyone tell how to redirect keycloak to open okta login in a pop up winodw using react/javascript.

Comment: Hard to answer. Are you using sso? Do you have a spa? Are you using callback and redirect? When login is successful, how should your iframe get notified? Why is popup a security issue?

Comment: We are using SPA and redirect. In your application, we have Login button within iframe. Once user to click on Login button, it should display keycloak login page (which redirect to okta login page). After login successfully, it will redirect to our application home page. Its working fine if login button not in iframe But it will throw error if its in iframe. Error from keycloak is "We're sorry...
An error occurred, please login again through your application".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i done :

=========== LoginButton Component ========

```
function LoginButton(props) {
 
  window.addEventListener('storage',event => {
   if (event.key === 'logged-user') {
            // update the redux store variable for login successful
  }
  });

  const clickHandler = () => {   
    const x = window.innerWidth / 2;
    const y = window.innerHeight / 2;
    const win=open('/login','Login',`width=500,height=600, left=${x},top=${y}`);
  };



  return (
    <>
      <Button
        onClick={clickHandler}
      > Login </Button>
     </>
   )
}

export default LoginButton
```

=========== Login Component ========

```
const LogIn = props => {
  const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();
  const [isLoginCalled, setIsLoginCalled] = useState(false);
  
  // load the profile and call saga for update login information
  function loadUserInfo() {
    keycloak
      .loadUserProfile()
      .then(function(profile) {
        localStorage.setItem('logged-user', profile.username);
        window.open('', '_self').close();
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(`Error while loading progile :${err}`);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(keycloak.authenticated && !isLoginCalled) {
      loadUserInfo();
      setIsLoginCalled(true);
    } else {    
      keycloak.login();      
    }
  }, [1]); 

  return (
    <>
     <h1>Loading please wait...</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export deault LogIn
```